# How to open the File Explorer to view the files in Angular 8 based on the anchor link clicked

Tags: angular

User can click on the anchor link given in the application UI and it should open the server folder in file explorer so user can view all the files/images/etc.

in HTML file:

```
<a (click)="goToLink()">Folder Open</a>
```

in TS file:

```
goToLink() {
    let url = "\\abc.COM\\docs\\prj_active";
    window.open(url, '_blank');
  }
```

But above code is not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the reason you need it. I haven't use that for any reason.

But I believe that you want something like this:

```
<a href="file:///C:/Documents/...">Anchor</a>
```

You should change your tags, that has nothing to do with Angular's ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I want to keep the server folder url to access to user. which is like "\\abc.COM\\docs\\prj_active" not the "C:/Documents"

Comment: That's the same thing, the important part is to pit the `file://` in the beginning.
Try to open your file with a browser to see the exact path in the URL above.